# "Fire" in the Android Jetboy Example App

Tags: android

I'm testing the "Jetboy" example Android code in an emulator.  It says "Use your fire button...".  Where is that? I've clicked all the buttons on my mouse, and hit about all the buttons on my keyboard, and I get nothing.

I was hoping that the following link would help, but I don't see my particular need in it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the relevant code inside [JetBoyView.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/JetBoy/src/com/example/android/jetboy/JetBoyView.html), check the `processKeyEvent()` method.
Fire is the DPAD center, thats usually pressing the trackball/-pad on a device. On the emulator it's this button:

[image]